# Problems with ZF2 form validation when used in a loop

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

My application has a web form that validates and saves user information, almost 30 fields total. There is also a CSV upload option and I am trying to re-use the Form and InputFilter classes I've created. I'm running into two issues. When I instantiate the form repeatedly, my memory consumption goes through the roof and eventually crashes with an out of memory exception.

```
foreach ($CSVdata as $data) {
    $form = new LocationForm();
    $filter = new LocationFilter();
    $form->setInputFilter($filter->getInputFilter());

    $form->setData($data);
    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        $messages[] = $form->getMessages();
    } else {
        $db->save($form->getData(\Zend\Form\FormInterface::VALUES_AS_ARRAY));
    }
}
```

I tried putting the code in a function and calling the function inside the loop, which in theory would release the memory when the objects go out of scope after the function exits but I still see memory climb approximately 300k per call until it runs out of memory.

So I tried instantiating the form object only once and just calling $form->setData() in the loop. This fixes the memory issue but now when I try to validate a row and an element fails validation, the messages array returned for that row contains every failed element of every previous row. For example:

```
$data[0] = array(a, b, c); // element 'b' fails validation. 
$messages[0] says 'b' failed validation.
$data[1] = array(a, b, c); // element 'c' fails validation. 
$messages[1] says BOTH 'b' and 'c' failed validation even though 'b' was actually valid!
```

Which I guess makes sense since I'm re-using the same form object. So my question is, is there a way to "reset" the form object or the input filter after each pass without re-instantiating either object? It seems like it's remembering or not re-initializing the messages array and I can't find a function to do it. Or am I going about this totally the wrong way? I really like the form validation and filtering in ZF2 but seems like no one is using it for validation of large data sets (or I'm just googling the wrong thing).

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the messages by using the following code anywhere inside your `LocationForm` class.

```
$this->messages = array();
```

If you need to do this in the loop, you could make a public function in `LocationForm` that has this line of code in it.  For example:

```
class LocationForm {
    public function resetForm() {
        $this->messages = array();
    }
}
```

Then in your loop, just call `$form->resetForm();`

Comment: `LocationFilter` will still have the messages and `LocationForm` just does `$this->setMessages($filter->getMessages())` on error

Comment: @Victory is partially correct. It looks like after validation, each element that fails validation has a $messages array that can be reset using the elements setMessages() function.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the Zend Form elements and methods I finally figured it out. Running the following code before calling $form->setData() clears out any error messages from the previous loop iteration:

```
$messages = $form->getInputFilter()->getMessages();
if (! empty($messages)) {
    foreach ($messages as $elementName => $validatorName) {
        $form->get($elementName)->setMessages(array($validatorName => null));
    }
}
```